# How to keep height of parent div with absolute positioned img inside?

Tags: css, positioning

```
<div id="show01">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png">
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

CSS

```
#show01{ 
    margin-top:14px; 
    position: relative;
    height:auto;
    border:thin solid blue;
}
#show01 img { 
  position: absolute;
    max-width:70%;
}
#content{
    background:#999;
    height:45px;
}
```

`img` must be `position:absolute` because they are subject of jquery slide show.

but, in that case div `content` goes to the top of page, because div `#show01` has no height. It's just a blue line at the top.

So, how can I keep img `position:absolute` and `show01` to have height as the `img` inside.

I cannot define div `show01` height in pixels, because of keeping responsive layout.

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gBNz6/)

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061682/2714670

The issue is the same ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is semi-hack(ish).. but you could set a margin for `#show01`.

Try `margin-bottom:24%;`.. see the example and let me know if this is what you were aiming for.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gBNz6/3/)

Basically you are going to have to set a margin equal to the size of the images to displace the unspecified height.. It seems to work responsively when you resize the browser too..

Comment: josh, seems works, but how do you know that `24%` is enough ? How do you get just `24%` ?

Comment: josh, very nice. Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: @JoshC Sorry Josh, I don't remember the previous time but sorry for that too :)