# How to position a div below another div that uses relative positioning, but absolute positioning for its elements?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a couple of slideshows going that require me to have the container to be `position: relative;` and its child elements (img's) must be 
`position: absolute;`

**Like So:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="frontimg">
   <div><img src="img/jackson.jpg"></div>
   <div><img src="img/custom.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .frontimg {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.frontimg img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
}
```

And then a small js script to make them fade in and out.

I am having trouble positioning another div below it. The div below it just seems to be hidden under it.

Comment: can you be more explicit, I am not sure I completely understand your question!

Comment: you need to specify a height either in the parent div or in the inner div, otherwise you need javascript to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the children of  ".frontimg" are not the images, but the div's that surround them.

try this:

```
.frontimg div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. It just made the div I am trying to position below them overlap them.

Answer (score 0):

If the images have a common height, you can simply give the `.frontimg` div either a set height, or bottom padding etc. to push the following elements down past the images. E.g.

```css
.frontimg {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
}

.frontimg img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
}

.next {border: 5px solid #30353b; background: #e7e7e7; min-height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="frontimg">
   <div><img src="https://unsplash.it/800/100"></div>
   <div><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x100"></div>
</div>

<div class="next">  
    <p>The following div</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the pictures don't have a set height. They are set using a width property. So they will be a different height dependent on the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

That div you want to stack under the slideshow is a `static` element, whilst the other elements are not (`display:relative,absolute, fixed` are out of the normal flow of static elements. Therefore you must assign that div a position of `absolute, fixed, or relative` so that it can interact with the other elements properly.

I added a demo that shows a div in two `position`s:

- click the div to toggle it's `position` from `static` to `absolute`.

### SNIPPET

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.div');

div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (div.classList.contains('static')) {
    div.classList.remove('static');
    div.classList.add('absolute');
  } else {
    div.classList.add('static');
    div.classList.remove('absolute');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.frontimg {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.frontimg img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
}
.div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  pointer-events:auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.static {
  position: static;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="frontimg">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/000/fff?text=1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/00f/fc0?text=2">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div static">DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061520/auto-height-on-parent-container-with-absolute-fixed-children), you need javascript (Jquery in this case) for achieve this effect. 
Add this Jquery code in your js file.

```
var biggestHeight = "0";
$(".frontimg *").each(function(){
if ($(this).height() > biggestHeight ) {
  biggestHeight = $(this).height()
}
});

$(".frontimg").height(biggestHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another div -

```
<div class = "someClass"> Some text </div>
```

Use `position:absolute` and assign a `top` property to define the position -

```
.someClass {
position: abolsute;
top : 40% //or whatever you like
}
```

You can also add a line break - `<br>`